# Nested ng-repeat is not working while parsing json data from a wordpress website

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I am developing a news app using Ionic. News is coming from a wordpress site in json format. Here is a small chunk of the json.

```
{
"status": "ok",
"count": 100,
"count_total": 4104,
"pages": 42,
"posts": [
    {
        "id": 57063,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "%e0%a6%b6%e0%a6%bf%e0%a6%ac%e0%a6%bf%e0%a6%b0%e0%a7%87%e0%a6%b0-%e0%a6%95%e0%a7%87%e0%a6%a8%e0%a7%8d%e0%a6%a6%e0%a7%8d%e0%a6%b0%e0%a7%80%e0%a7%9f-%e0%a6%a8%e0%a7%87%e0%a6%a4%e0%a6%be-%e0%a6%8f",
        "url": "http://latestkhobor.com/%e0%a6%b8%e0%a6%be%e0%a6%b0%e0%a6%be%e0%a6%a6%e0%a7%87%e0%a6%b6/%e0%a6%9a%e0%a6%9f%e0%a7%8d%e0%a6%9f%e0%a6%97%e0%a7%8d%e0%a6%b0%e0%a6%be%e0%a6%ae-%e0%a6%ac%e0%a6%bf%e0%a6%ad%e0%a6%be%e0%a6%97/%e0%a6%b6%e0%a6%bf%e0%a6%ac%e0%a6%bf%e0%a6%b0%e0%a7%87%e0%a6%b0-%e0%a6%95%e0%a7%87%e0%a6%a8%e0%a7%8d%e0%a6%a6%e0%a7%8d%e0%a6%b0%e0%a7%80%e0%a7%9f-%e0%a6%a8%e0%a7%87%e0%a6%a4%e0%a6%be-%e0%a6%8f/",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "শিবিরের কেন্দ্রীয় নেতা এনামুল চট্টগ্রামে গ্রেফতার",
        "title_plain": "শিবিরের কেন্দ্রীয় নেতা এনামুল চট্টগ্রামে গ্রেফতার",
        "content": "<p style=\"text-align: justify;\"><a href=\"http://latestkhobor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/enamul_224231.jpg\"><img class=\"alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-57037\" src=\"http://latestkhobor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/enamul_224231-150x150.jpg\" alt=\"enamul_224231.jpg\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\" /></a>নাশকতার অভিযোগে ছাত্রশিবিরের কেন্দ্রীয় কার্যকরী পরিষদের সদস্য এনামুল কবিরকে গ্রেফতার করেছে চট্টগ্রাম মহানগর পুলিশ। শুক্রবার তাকে নগরীর বাকলিয়া থানার বগার বিল এলাকা থেকে গ্রেফতার করে পুলিশ।</p>\n<p style=\"text-align: justify;\">নগর পুলিশের অতিরিক্ত কমিশনার (অপরাধ ও অভিযান) বনজ কুমার মজুমদার গ্রেপ্তারের বিষয়টি নিশ্চিত করেছেন।</p>\n<p style=\"text-align: justify;\">পুলিশ সূত্রে জানা গেছে এ বিষয়ে আরো জানানো হয়, এনামুলের সঙ্গে চট্টগ্রামেরও কয়েকজন শিবিরের নেতাকর্মীকে আটক করা হয়েছে।</p>\n",
        "excerpt": "<p>নাশকতার অভিযোগে ছাত্রশিবিরের কেন্দ্রীয় কার্যকরী পরিষদের সদস্য এনামুল কবিরকে গ্রেফতার করেছে চট্টগ্রাম মহানগর পুলিশ। শুক্রবার তাকে নগরীর বাকলিয়া থানার বগার বিল এলাকা থেকে গ্রেফতার করে পুলিশ। নগর পুলিশের অতিরিক্ত কমিশনার (অপরাধ ও অভিযান) বনজ কুমার মজুমদার গ্রেপ্তারের বিষয়টি নিশ্চিত করেছেন। পুলিশ সূত্রে জানা গেছে এ বিষয়ে আরো জানানো হয়, এনামুলের সঙ্গে চট্টগ্রামেরও কয়েকজন শিবিরের নেতাকর্মীকে &#8230;</p>\n",
        "date": "2015-02-21 15:38:41",
        "modified": "2015-02-21 15:38:41",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 960,
                "slug": "%e0%a6%9a%e0%a6%9f%e0%a7%8d%e0%a6%9f%e0%a6%97%e0%a7%8d%e0%a6%b0%e0%a6%be%e0%a6%ae-%e0%a6%ac%e0%a6%bf%e0%a6%ad%e0%a6%be%e0%a6%97",
                "title": "চট্টগ্রাম বিভাগ",
                "description": "",
                "parent": 11,
                "post_count": 50
            },
            {
                "id": 48,
                "slug": "%e0%a6%ac%e0%a7%8d%e0%a6%b0%e0%a7%87%e0%a6%95%e0%a6%bf%e0%a6%82-%e0%a6%a8%e0%a6%bf%e0%a6%89%e0%a6%9c",
                "title": "breaking",
                "description": "",
                "parent": 0,
                "post_count": 1132
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "slug": "%e0%a6%b8%e0%a6%be%e0%a6%b0%e0%a6%be%e0%a6%a6%e0%a7%87%e0%a6%b6",
                "title": "সারাদেশ",
                "description": "",
                "parent": 0,
                "post_count": 1347
            }
        ],
```

I want to show a particular news sorting by category. Like I want to show news what is into "breaking" category. I tried this code but it's not happening right.

```
<ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left"  ng-repeat="singleNews in news.posts" href="#/app/singleNews/{{singleNews.id}}">
            <span ng-repeat="cat in singleNews.categories | filter: {title: 'breaking'}">
                <img src="{{singleNews.thumbnail}}">
                <h2 ng-bind-html="singleNews.title"></h2>
                <div ng-bind-html="singleNews.excerpt"></div>
            </span>
 </ion-item>
```

Comment: try `ng-repeat="cat in singleNews.categories | filter: {title: 'breaking'}:true"` this will perform strict check

Comment: No it's not happening. it's trying to show the whole list of news from the json data but every list is blank except where it's matches the breaking category.So, it can match the "breaking" category because I can see only the thumbnail of the breaking category in my list where it's matched.

Comment: I can't see thumbail in your json source data above.

Comment: can you create fiddle or plunkr, or just send you whole response so we can try something

Comment: This json code chunk is not containing the thumbnail, It's in the main json  file. @jyrkim

Comment: Hi @pankajparkar I have setup a codepen. Actually the second ng-repeat is working but as I said so it's trying to show the whole list of news from the json data. And the span tag for second ng-repeat is the culprit for the Ionic css, that's why the thumbnail image is shown over the content. Please see the project [here](http://codepen.io/ahayder/pen/MYGYOp)

Comment: @AliHayder  Correct me if I'm wrong, you want to show that single row which is matching `title: 'breaking'`

Comment: @pankajparkar not a single row. I want to show all the news/rows that matches the particular category's title.

Comment: Ok that means only the row which are matching filtering criteria

Comment: Yes Exactly. @pankajparkar

Comment: @AliHayder I'm looking into it

Comment: @pankajparkar I have solved the problem just now by a little trick. I am writing answer to this question by working code. :) Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe for better solution you need to create a custom filter. that will filter out if title is matching `{title: 'special'}`

```
app.filter('filterForTitle',function($filter){
  return function(news, prop1){
    var returnValue = [];
    angular.forEach(news,function(values,index){
      var matchedValue = $filter('filter')(values.categories,{title:'special'},true);
      if(matchedValue.length>0) returnValue.push(values);
    });
    return returnValue;
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left" href="#/app/singleNews/{{singleNews.id}}" ng-repeat="singleNews in news.posts|filterForTitle">
    <img src="{{singleNews.thumbnail}}">
    <h2 ng-bind-html="singleNews.title"></h2>
    <div ng-bind-html="singleNews.excerpt"></div>
</ion-item>
```

[**Working CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYxemG)

Filtered array is returning duplicate values everytime, i think service is only returning duplicate values.

For solving that issue we need to filter for inner `ng-repeat` like `filter:{title: 'special'}"` Thats weird part .

Comment: Sorry to say pankaj it's not working right. the thumbnail image should appear left to it's respective content like this [Working Pen](http://codepen.io/ahayder/pen/MYGYOp).
I can't come up with a better idea than my solution above. :(

Comment: @AliHayder actually i was added extra div which i removed now.All working fine now

Comment: @AliHayder did you looked at my updated answer,Does it work properly? i hope this a better way to create a filter & use filtered data on UI directly rather than use workarounds..

Comment: yup I saw it and it's a better solution comparing to my solution. :)

Comment: @AliHayder then why you don't accept it? There might be not better way than this, the solution you are using it has filter twice and in mine its filtering only once..Thanks :)

Comment: I accepted it :), but I somehow forgot to voteup you, it was my bad.

Comment: Though both answers are correct respect to my question. Leave it please, I marked your answer. :)

Comment: @AlyHayder Thanks pal.Glad to help you..Didn't knew about angular-ionic.Still spend more than couple of hours on it..enjoyed coding..Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I did a little trick and it worked. I just wrote the first ng-repeat outside of the ion-item tag. Here is the working code of the ion-list

```
<div ng-repeat="singleNews in news.posts">
  <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="cat in singleNews.categories | filter: {title: 'ক্রিকেট'}" href="#/app/singleNews/{{singleNews.id}}">
     <img src="{{singleNews.thumbnail}}">
     <h2 ng-bind-html="singleNews.title"></h2>
     <div ng-bind-html="singleNews.excerpt"></div>
  </ion-item>
</div>
```

Comment: I also found the same..but is it valid to create div inside ion-list

Comment: not valid though, Please inform me if you find any perfect solution.

Comment: Sure currently I'm doing the same..will let you know one i found anything]